# screen needs to be shifted

Tags: screen, resize

My screen is shifted over to far to the right. It turns out there is a blank part on the left of the screen, and scroll bar cut off on the right. I cant find anything on my monitor for shifting it. So I think its on my PC instead.
Thanks

Comment: Is this an old-style CRT?

Comment: this is  an hd flat scren monitor

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a VGA connector,

[image: © User:Swift.Hg / Wikimedia Commons / CC-BY-SA-3.0]

the signal from the computer doesn't contain explicit information about the screen resolution, so the LCD monitor must make an educated guess about how to align the picture.

Some monitors don't do this step automatically, since it could be distracting if the alignment was changed unnecessarily. Check for a menu item or a physical button labeled to the effect of "Auto Adjust", which should force the monitor to align the current signal.